# "ng generate application xyz" CLI not woking

Tags: angular6, angular-cli-v6

### I am trying to add an application to existing project but it's failing when running "ng generate application xyz". Error is:

Schematic input does not validate against the Schema: {"sourceDir":"app","prefix":"app","style":"css","theme":true,"webpack":true}
Errors:

### Data path "" should have required property 'name'.

I then used "ng generate application --name=xyz" and the full blown subproject was created but I get the error when I run "ng serve xyz" which says "Project 'xyz' could not be found in workspace.". I Googled but I found nothing matching my problem. All examples generate libraries but I want to generate application not library.

Do I need to manually add the newly generated sub project settings to parent angular.json file?

ng -v
Angular CLI: 6.1.5
Node: 8.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.1.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

```
Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.7.5
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.7.5
@angular-devkit/core              0.7.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.7.5
@angular/cli                      6.1.5
@ngtools/webpack                  6.1.5
@schematics/angular               0.7.5
@schematics/update                0.7.5
rxjs                              6.3.1
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.9.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1026#issuecomment-387167984) you need to add a **--name flag** in the older version of the cli.

```
ng generate application --name xyz
```

And it seems to be a [fixed issue](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/1026#issuecomment-387194595).